# Display connected vertices in UV editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Is there any way to show other vertices attached to the current activated vertex in the uv editor without enabling "sticking selection mode"?

Answer (score 1):

Press the letter L with your mouse over some vertex.

<kbd>L</kbd>

Sometimes with a current selection

<kbd>CTRL-L</kbd>

Comment: Both shortcut seems to execute an "island selection of the current vertex", i don't see any helpers about other connected vertices.